# Expanding maps in 2 or more dimensions: bounded preimages

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Here is a quick question regarding expanding maps.

Suppose that $M$ is a closed (compact) manifold endowed with a Riemannian metric.

Take a map $F: M \to M$ which is continuously differentiable and satisfies

$$\inf_{\substack{\phantom{a}\\ x\,\in\,S}}\left(\inf_{\substack{\phantom{a}\\ v\,\in\, T_xM}} \left.\frac{\|D_xFv\|}{\|v\|} \right.\right)\ge \lambda > 1,$$

where the norms above are those of the Riemannian metric in the tangent spaces of $x$ and $F(x)$.

**Question.** Is this a sufficient condition to conclude that the number of preimages of any point is bounded across $M$?

*i.e.*, Does it follow from these assumptions that

$$  \sup_{x\in S}\big|\, F^{-1}(x)\, \big|< \infty\;?$$

If not, in what settings/dimensions does it hold, or what further assumptions are required?

Comment: Sure, any such map is a local diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have it, with the help of @JohnB's comment.

Indeed it is true that $F$ must be a local diffeomorphism (as the inf-inf equation means that $D_xF$ has no zero eigenvalues and therefore is of full rank, for any $x$) and that's enough to conclude.

Firstly, it follows that a given $x\in M$ can have only finitely many preimages: otherwise, by compactness of $M$, its set of preimages $F^{-1}(x)$ has an accumulation point; and there's no way $F$ can be injective on a neighbourhood of this point $\leadsto$ contradiction.

Secondly, the function $x \mapsto |F^{-1}(x)|$ is locally constant and therefore constant on each of the [finitely many] connected components of $M$. That affirms my question. This is a little harder to prove, but here is a sketch:

Suppose that $F^{-1}(x) = \{y_1,\ldots y_n\}$. We can certainly find/construct open neighbourhoods, $U,V_1,\ldots V_n$ of $x,y_1,\ldots y_n$ respectively, such that $F:V_i\to U$ is a diffeomorphism for each $i$.

It is immediate that every point in $U$ must have at least $n$ preimages, one in each of the $V_i$. Moreover, if there is a sequence of points in $U$, $(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty \to x$ each with more than $n$ preimages, we can create a sequence $(z_k)$ with $F(z_k) = x_k$ and the property that each $z_k$ does not lie in any $V_i$. Again by compactness, we can take $z$ as an accumulation point of this sequence, and by continuity it must lie in $F^{-1}(x)$, therefore one of the $V_i$'s.

Thereby $(z_k)$ would have to enter one of the $V_i$'s, a contradiction.

Comment: Simpler like this: Consider local diffeomorphisms $F|_{U_p}$ obtained from $F$ on a neighborhood $U_p$ of each point $p$. Take a finite subcover $U_{p_1},\ldots,U_{p_n}$. Then  each point has at most a number $n$ of preimages.

Comment: Thanks for this @JohnB! That is considerably easier, and you even the "local constancy" above follows easily by pushing the $U_i$ cover forward,.

**Further to this**, I'm wondering whether one can bound the number terms of $|F^{-1}(x)|$ in terms of $\lambda$, or if it is necessary to assume more.

**Also** Is it also, true that $M$ being compact must have finite volume?

Comment: Not the number of elements of $F^{-1}x$ since that depends on the size of $M$, but you can bound the number of elements of $F^{-n}x$ in terms of $\lambda^n$ up to a universal constant (independent of $n$). Incidentally, there are no adapted norms for expanding maps, but the reason why there is a constant above is different.